# Convert Mathematica expression to Python expression

Tags: python

[image]

I really need to convert this expression to python language, however I am having trouble converting Bessel function (Actually I have several similar expression and to know how to convert really would help me )

Comment: Apart from implementing the `BesselJ` symbolically, perhaps you can use a method of passing computation back and forth between the `ExternalEvaluate` of Python in Mathematica?

Comment: not a good idea to just post image, since it is a little hard to copy code from an image to a notebook.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this question is off topic here as it does not really involve _Mathematica_.

Answer (score 1):

How about using sympy in Python and the Bessel function implementations?

[sympy: Bessel](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html#sympy.functions.special.bessel.BesselBase)